# how to write a recursive fn to eval the below structure

Tags: clojure

I have a structure where the first element is a function, and the rest args to the fn. Now each arg could in turn be a vector with similar charectristic.

`[+ 1 2 3 [- 4 3] 5 6 [- 9 8 [+ 5 6]] 4 5]`

How do I write a recursive fn to calculate the result given any such vector ? Also is there any way to just eval it, as the structure will be a valid clojure form if the vector can be replaced by () ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user=> (def d '[+ 1 2 3 [- 4 3] 5 6 [- 9 8 [+ 5 6]] 4 5])
#'user/d
user=> (defn to-list [elt]
  #_=>   (if (vector? elt) (map to-list elt) elt))
user=> (to-list d)
(+ 1 2 3 (- 4 3) 5 6 (- 9 8 (+ 5 6)) 4 5)
user=> (eval *1)
17
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that `eval` will take a pretty significant amount of time here:

```
;; to-list as in Michiel's answer, v is the example from the question
user=> (time (dotimes [_ 100] (eval (to-list v))))
"Elapsed time: 192.098235 msecs"
```

A simple custom function can be more than an order of magnitude faster:

```
user=> (defn calcvec [v]
         (if (vector? v)
           (apply (resolve (first v))
                  (map calcvec (next v)))
           v))
#'user/calcvec
user=> (calcvec v)
17
user=> (time (dotimes [_ 100] (calcvec v)))
"Elapsed time: 15.87096 msecs"
```

I tried to benchmark these with Criterium, but `quick-bench` takes *way* too long on the `eval` version, so I ended up killing it. (It does fine with `calcvec`, though.)

Generally speaking, `eval` makes the most sense for operations performed rarely (perhaps only once), such as compiling a function from a dynamically constructed piece of code etc. So, if you only need to compute the values of a handful such vectors, the `eval` approach is fine; otherwise you'll be better off with `calcvec` or something similar. It goes without saying that the `eval` version can do much more, for example it will handle special forms and macros.